# Cannot create image from encoded string in C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on an app that needs to write a .png image file from a Base64 encoded string. In an attempt to do this, I have the following code:

```
byte[] tempBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedString);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(tempBytes))
{
  System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
  image.Save("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MySite\\test.png");
}
```

When this code executes, I receive the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException Parameter is not valid.
```

The relevant part of the stack trace looks like:

```
at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
```

From my understanding, this means that my base64encodedString is not a valid image. However, I have no clue how to identify what the cause could be. The code above is run on the server. I'm passing the encoded string from a client app that i have also written. I've printed the encoded string on the client-side and also on the server side to ensure they match. Considering the two match, it would imply that I'm not encoding the string properly. How can I trace back the cause.

Thank you

Comment: Try to insert `memoryStream.Position = 0;` before call to `Save`

Comment: Where are you getting the Base64 encoded string?

Comment: Is the Base64 encoded string just the binary data of the image? If so why don't you just write the binary data directly to a file and not use `System.Drawing.Image`.

Comment: You could try comparing the original non-encoded file contents from the client to the decoded contents on the server.

Comment: Since you own the client as well (a great help, by the way) you should run your server side code that you just posted above on the client immediately after encoding the image, and see if you get the same error. Trace back to see where the corruption happens.

Comment: Perhaps posting a relevant portion of your client code could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to serialize the image first. (then deserialize on decode)